# How to show one page for all routes in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5

In my work I need to show on page for all routes instead of `/api` route, for example

```
Route::group([

    'prefix' => 'panel',
    'middleware' => [ 'auth' ]

], function() {

    Route::any('{all}', 'HomeController@index')
        ->where('all', '.*');

    Route::group([

        'prefix' => 'api'

    ], function() {

        Route::get('catalog/{item?}', 'CatalogController@index');
    });
});
```

But this is not working.

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? You can go to `/panel/api/catalog` and you see the result of `CatalogController@index`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved

```
Route::any('{all?}', 'HomeController@index')
->where('all', '.+');
```